# EndPoint retrofit URL missing slash

Tags: android, retrofit

I'm using the url: https://fsp.com.br/?s=12&p=25

Base URL: https://fsp.com.br/

I've tryed:

```
@GET("") 
Call<String> getStringResponse(@Query("s") int s, @Query("p") int p);

@GET(".") 
Call<String> getStringResponse(@Query("s") int s, @Query("p") int p);

@GET("./") 
Call<String> getStringResponse(@Query("s") int s, @Query("p") int p);
```

But it's not solving the url.

If I do:

```
@GET("a") 
Call<String> getStringResponse(@Query("s") int s, @Query("p") int p);
```

Returning: https://fsp.com.br/a?s=12&p=25

How to solve the url https://fsp.com.br/?s=12&p=25 using retrofi.

Comment: @GET("./") works

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
@GET 
Call<String> getStringResponse(@Url String yourUrl, @Query("s") int s, @Query("p") int p);
```